# Обратная совместимость mingw компилятора

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mingw

Программируя на C++ под *Windows*, привык, что компиляторы от MS не имеют обратной совместимости, потому компилируются библиотеки отдельно для vc10, vc12, vc14. Стала задача портирования приложения на mingw, тут версии 4.8, 4.9, 5.3. Как здесь обстоит ситуация с обратной совместимостью? Если скомпилирую библиотеку в 4.8, смогу ли я прилинковать к приложению на 4.9? А на 5.3?

**Update**

Не совсем понятны комментарии про IDE. обычно стараюсь делать, чтоб проект можно было собрать выполнением скрипта, при наличие только компилятора.

Более конкретный пример: я разработал библиотеку сериализации классов в xml файл, собрал библиотеку с vc10, имеем h-файл, lib-файл для линковки и dll-файл для выполнения. Эту библиотеку я без проблем линкую и использую с приложениями, собранными на vc10. Я могу без проблем библиотеку слинковать с проектом vc12. Но вот при выполнение получу segmentation fault или другие подобные проблемы. Банально, потому что `std::string` в vc10 и vc12 реализованы немного по разному (может и не `std::string`, а что-то другое).

Так вот собственно вопрос: я собрал библиотеку с помощью migw 4.8, получу lib, dll. Смогу ли я использовать эти lib и dll для сборки программы под mingw 5.3, не пересобирая свою библиотеку под 5.3?

Comment: Если я правильно помню, то гарантируется совместимость по бинарникам в пределах "мажорной версии". То есть, бинарники от 4.8 и 4.9 будут совместимы, а вот 5.3 и 4.8 - а кто его знает. В целом, нужно гуглить на тему gcc abi

Comment: я натыкался на проблемы, когда компилировал код 4.8, а буст при этом был собран 5.3 (падал код, который инициализировал как раз string из бустовой error_code.message()). По умолчанию, кажется, можно считать, что 4.х и 5.х не совместимы.

Answer (score 1):

В gcc 5.1 появился новый ABI: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Думаю, на mingw это тоже отразилось.

Поэтому для версии 5.2 советую сначала, как минимум, 
поставить значение макроса _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI в 0, 
чтобы использовался старый ABI.